# Windows 7 SP1 login screen freeze

Tags: windows-7, freeze

When login screen appears, both mouse and keyboard aren't working.

I do shutdown via powerbutton, Windows 7 notices that and changes screen to 'Shutting down' spinner. Once rebooted, freezes once again.

**However,** if I don't allow 'clean' shutdown, by keep pressing power, on next boot up all works -- I can login and every app seems fine.

Only events of 'Error' type I see in Event log are:

1. Application subnode: `Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.`
2. System subnode: `SAM failed to start the TCP/IP or SPX/IPX listening thread`.

Motherboard is Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD3H, BIOS ver F4. As I've said, once logged in, everything works fine, so it's not a processor or RAM, or video, or hard drive.

What could it be?

---

**UPDATE** Safe mode does not help after clean shutdown: login screen appears at lower resolution, but input devices still not working. Interestingly, even screen suspension works -- I've left system for ~10 min and screen gone to sleep (and woke up after I poked power button).

Thank you!

Comment: FYI: the error you see regarding WMI and the Processor > 99 deal is a known Win7 SP1 bug, and has nothing to do with your problem. See this MS KB entry: [Event ID 10 is logged in the Application log after you install Service Pack 1 for Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2545227)

Comment: If you do a clean shutdown, does it work as expected if you then boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: Ok, perhaps then I should post whole sequence of events from event log which occur during boot?

Comment: I haven't done Safe mode, mostly because Windows hasn't offered me it, neither after clean nor after forced shutdown (and because once I reboot after forced shutdown, everything OK). I'll try Safe mode after clean shutdown, ok.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Safe mode doesn't help after clean shutdown. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, you're not performing a "clean" shutdown, it's call a Hard shutdown/reset. (Where you press and hold the power button to get it to shut off.) If this is in fact the case your HDD likely has bad sectors on it that can easily be repaired, for free, by using a [bootable repair disc](http://jai-fixyourpc.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-fix-bad-sectors-in-your-hard.html), running chkdsk when you can get to the desktop, etc...

You mention it's not hardware, have you run any diagnostics tests? Or is "once logged in, everything works fine" your diagnosis so far?

I recommend:

~ Running bootable or live software to double check your hardware, mainly the HDD.
~ Run basic repair commands like `chkdsk`, `sfc /scannow`, `bootrec.exe /fixboot`
~ Try what's literally called a clean boot through [MSCONFIG](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135)

Comment: yea chkdsk with the /F option >chkdsk C: /F  is more likely to finish clearing out any messes made by hard reset Then on the system disk it will have to happen offline at a reboot you would want to do that (clean proper) reboot sooner than later..

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fixed (few logons w/o freezes) by installing `Intel USB 3.0 Driver` from Gigabyte's download page for my motherboard.

Sad thing that page has lot of downloadable hotfixes/drivers, so it's easy to miss something important; single download package would be more convenient.